# calculate the number of years in a csv file using pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, datetime

i have a csv file containing  years of data , and i am using pandas to read it.
my main request, is how to calculate the number of years from the max date and the min date .

```
timestamp,heure,lat,lon,impact,type
2007-01-01 00:00:00,13:58:43,33.837,-9.205,10.3,1
2007-01-02 00:00:00,00:07:28,34.5293,-10.2384,17.7,1
2007-01-02 00:00:00,23:01:03,35.0617,-1.435,-17.1,2
2007-01-03 00:00:00,01:14:29,36.5685,0.9043,36.8,1
2007-01-03 00:00:00,05:03:51,34.1919,-12.5061,-48.9,1
```

I am proceeding as below :

```
data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time'])
DateMax = data.index.max()
DateMin = data.index.min()
NByears = (DateMax - DateMin).astype('datetime64[Y]')
```

but it's not working, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need first convert to [`DatetimeIndex.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.year.html), get `min` and `max` and last subtract:

```
DateMax = data.index.year.max()
DateMin = data.index.year.min()
NByears = (DateMax - DateMin)
```